# How to copy folder and website shortcuts from device to device (on many devices)

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, home-screen

I work for a company that purchases 100+ customized tablets, that are then given to a client when he buys a product. Instead of a brochure, the client walks away with this customized (cheap) tablet, preloaded with some material.

What I have to do is to install PDF reader and EZ File Explorer.

EX File Explorer allows me to put folder shortcut to the home screen, and Chrome allows me to add website shortcuts to the home screen.

Doing this on all 150 tablets (once in 3 months) takes **forever**!

Would anybody know any solution how to copy and paste the shortcuts from one to the other?

So far I have not come up with any solution. The Chrome shortcuts cannot be copied (as far as I know) and I did not find a way to put on the screen shortcuts that could be copied. Similar with the folders.

Any help would save HOURS!!!

Thanks

Comment: Google summarizes the different provisioning methods: https://developers.google.com/android/management/provision-device#provisioning_methods

Answer (score 0):

A possible way to export the shortcuts is to first install another launcher for example [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher), then create the shortcuts. Open Nova Launcher settings, go to "Backup & import settings" click on "Backup". Save your configuration to an SD card.

Install Nova Launcher on another tablet, open its settings -> "Backup & import settings", click on "Restore or manage backups", select the backup from the SD card. The shortcuts will be recreated.

Comment: Thanks Reddy, would this backup both, the website shortcuts as well as the folder shortcuts?

Comment: @MartinP As long as you are creating, importing and restoring them using the same launcher, yes. You can test it with your phone or tablet. Create shortcuts and folders, back them up, delete them and try to restore them.

Comment: I use Nova launcher and have just tried a backup and restore between a Pixel 5 and new Pixel 7. All my web shortcuts are transferred across, but greyed out and not working.